# Codename one Android Push Notifications being dismissed immediately

Tags: codenameone

I am sending a push notification from my web application and it is working great on IOS, but on Android the notification is only noticeable for a brief second (probably more like a couple milliseconds) as the notification icon along the top blips. There is no nitrification in the notification alerts list (preview).

I have registered the app with google per the Developer guide (Android Bureaucracy). And I can tell the app is getting the notification if I show it in a dialog. I just want the system notification to stick so the user knows they need to check the app.

App Code:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        Display.getInstance().registerPush();
    });

    // show the splash screen
    splashScreen.show();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    if(current instanceof Dialog) {
        ((Dialog)current).dispose();
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }
}

public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void push(String value) {
    //Dialog.show("push", "value:" + value, "OK", "Cancel");
}

@Override
public void registeredForPush(String deviceId) {
    //String pushKey = Push.getPushKey();
    //System.out.println("deviceId:" + deviceId + ", pushKey:" + pushKey);
}

@Override
public void pushRegistrationError(String error, int errorCode) {
    //System.out.println("Unable to register push:" + errorCode + ":" + error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the app is running the push will implicitly be dismissed and this should be the case both for Android & iOS. If the app is in the background or not running the push should remain in the tray until it is clicked.

Comment: This issue is happening when the app is in the background on Android only. When the app is in the background on IOS the notification is operating as you describe, correctly.

Comment: Any more thoughts on why it is acting like the app is in the foreground when it is not? This is our last major hurdle to releasing.

Comment: This isn't happening to our apps so let's try to understand the differences. Is this happening on more than one device? Are you using any cn1libs? Do you have a background process type? Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I am using the fingerprint cn1lib. I have only tested the app on one android device and one iOS device. I can try and find another android device to test. Question, do I need to do anything in the "push" callback to get this functionality? Seems like I would not since the app is in the background or not running. The app does not have a background process.

Comment: No you don't need to do anything, this should "just work". I don't see anything related to fingerprint that should impact this and technically this should work as far back as Android 2.3.x but there might be something "weird" going on. Can you connect the device with a cable and launch DDMS or logcat and provide us with the logs when the push is received?

Comment: Phone info:
Sansung Galaxy S7 Edge
Model Number: SM-G935V
Android Version: 7

Comment: I have a file with troubleshooting info from support, according to them the app is not compatible with the phone. Where can I email the file to?

Comment: Can you send it to the support email or thru the chat UI in the website?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that there was a security app on the phone called Security 360 that was blocking the notification.